# A body moving along a circular path covers a distance of 3 m in 1 s uniformly

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics

A body moving along a circular path covers a distance of 3 m in 1 s uniformly, such that the body returns to its starting point.

(i) Is the body moving with uniform speed? Explain.

(ii) Is the body moving with uniform velocity? Explain

(iii) Is the motion of body along the circular path accelerated? Explain.

Please answer the question. I would be grateful... Thanks...

I can think that body is moving with uniform speed 3m/s. But fails to explain. Also body is not moving with uniform velocity as velocity is a vector quantity and body would change the direction along the circular path and thus velocity is changing every moment.

Also despite no change in speed, the body is accelerating because its direction changes all the time.

Please write in details...question wise...

I dont have enough points to comment so...
a) the body is moving with uniform speed, because the object is covering a CONSTANTly increasing distance over time. And speed is directionless

b)the body is moving with a constantly changing velocity, because velocity=speed+direction, and the direction (linear) is constantly changing in a circle (tangents on the circle).

c) as an object moves in a circle, it is constantly accelerating, because objects like to move in a straight path (inertia and stuff), so to redirect that path constantly forming infinite straight line tangents on the circle, you need to apply a force to the object to turn its path. Because as newton once said, "object+force+change in position=acceleration" or something like that.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: Sir. This is not a my homework questions. I am learning physics of my own... Help is appreciated..

Comment: Hint: the body moves with without acceleration == body's velocity is constant == body moves along the straight line or is at rest.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. You already answered (ii) and (iii) correctly - there is not much to add. As for part (i) I do not understand the question. It's a given that "body moving along a circular path covers a distance of 3 m in 1 s uniformly" - for me it's the same as "the body moving with uniform speed".

Comment: You can always comment on your own posts. But that added info belongs in the question, it certainly doesn't belong in the comments. Your question is a lot better now, but you should try to narrow it down to the specific concepts you're still having trouble with, as the meta link explains.